# Programming a simple Stock prediction service with Alpha Vantage in Python. I get this error

Tags: python-3.x, alpha-vantage

This is the program for the stock prediction to be simply printed...

```
  from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
    # Your key here
    key = 'yourkeyhere'
    ts = TimeSeries(key)
    aapl, meta = ts.get_daily(symbol='AAPL')
    print(aapl['2020-22-5'])
```

I get this error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/AlphaVantageTest/AlphaVantageTest.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(aapl['2020-22-5'])
KeyError: '2020-22-5'
```

Since that didn't work, I tried getting a little more technical with it...

```
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
from alpha_vantage.techindicators import TechIndicators
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Your key here
key = 'W01B6S3ALTS82VRF'
# Chose your output format, or default to JSON (python dict)
ts = TimeSeries(key, output_format='pandas')
ti = TechIndicators(key)

# Get the data, returns a tuple
# aapl_data is a pandas dataframe, aapl_meta_data is a dict
aapl_data, aapl_meta_data = ts.get_daily(symbol='AAPL')
# aapl_sma is a dict, aapl_meta_sma also a dict
aapl_sma, aapl_meta_sma = ti.get_sma(symbol='AAPL')


# Visualization
figure(num=None, figsize=(15, 6), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
aapl_data['4. close'].plot()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

I get these errors...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/AlphaVantageTest/AlphaVantageTest.py", line 9, in <module>
    ts = TimeSeries(key, output_format='pandas')
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\AlphaVantageTest\venv\lib\site-packages\alpha_vantage\alphavantage.py", line 66, in __init__
    raise ValueError("The pandas library was not found, therefore can "
ValueError: The pandas library was not found, therefore can not be used as an output format, please install manually
```

How can I improve my program so that I don't receive these errors? None of these programs are bad syntax wise. Thank you to anyone that can help.

Comment: have you tried `pip install pandas`? Or installing pandas to your venv using whichever call you need depending on your venv flavor...

Comment: run `pip freeze` and look for pandas. If it's not there, pandas is not installed.

Comment: @Mason Caiby. This worked! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install pandas. If you're just using pip, you can run `pip install pandas` if you are using conda to manage your envs you can use `conda install pandas`.

---

Glad it worked. According to this meta overflow post: [What if I answer a question in a comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294791/what-if-i-answer-a-question-in-a-comment)
I am posting my comment as an answer so you can mark the question as answered.